# Rails: Fail to pass multiple variable-ids to nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

In my project are 2 nested resources:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :posts do
    resources :comments 
end
root 'posts#index'
end
```

I'm rendering a collection of comments with the use of a partial _comment.html.erb

```
    <%= render partial: "comments/comment", collection: @post.comments %>
```

The partial looks like this

```
<div class="comment_wrapper">
    <p class="comment_name"><%= comment.name %></p>
    <p class="comment_date"><%= comment.created_at %></p>
    <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <%= link_to "Delete comment", post_comment_path(@post.id, id: comment.id), method: :delete%>
</div>
```

The problem is with that nested route in the "Delete comment" link.
I keep failing to pass in the `:id` key. I've tried a couple of different ways to pass the variables in the link, but keep getting the same error, that the `:id` key is missing. When I replace the link with a paragraph to display `comment.id`, it gets displayed perfectly, so it's definately available in my view.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :post_id=>11} missing required keys: [:id]
```

As you can see it also tries to call the "show" action, but I bet that will be solved as soon as it passes the ids properly.
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the error is

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :format=>nil, :id=>**nil**, :post_id=>11}

And in your link_to has comment.id in it:

```
<%= link_to "Delete comment", post_comment_path(@post.id, id: comment.id), method: :delete %>
```

It means that you are passing an object with no id in it (not saved in database). You are probably building your comments and that is the reason they do not have ids yet.

One of the solutions to this problem is to use your link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to("Delete comment", post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :delete) unless comment.new_record? %>
```

Which will not show the link for new records, because you can't delete what does not exist in database yet.

Comment: Hey woaw thanks, I would have never figured that out by myself!
In the `show` action of my PostController I indeed have a new comment defined, so that I can have a form for creating comments at the bottom of show.html.erb. But of course that comment hasn't been saved yet.

Thanks again Gen!

Comment: @sjbuysse, sure, thing. I guess everyone learned about this error in the same way. Please accept the answer, if it worked out for you. Thank you.